# Calling data from a java script object with a variable and dot format

Tags: javascript

I have a const object, player, and inside that, I have several things one of which is playerResources.

```
const player ={
    // other things
        playerResources:{
            tree1:{
                unlocked: true,
                level: 0,
                type: "Magic Tree",
                hp: 100,
                id: "#playerTree1Prog",
                did:"playerTree1",
                cid:"treeContainer1",
                yeild: 110,
                respawnRate: 1,
                resourceText: "Hits Remaining"
            }
       // more resources
      }
    }
```

Now I am trying to find a way to call these different resources values using a variable. Like this.

```
var LVL = player.playerResources.VAR.level;
```

I have tried it with how it is above, I have looked into Object.keys and several other things that looked like it might be a solution, but I'm 3 hours and a few hundred pages deep in Google. So I figured it was time to come to the experts.

here is my question: Is this even possible, and if it is what is it called and if you have the time how does one implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bracket format:

```
player.playerResources[VAR].level
```

E.g. if VAR is `"tree1"` it will return the level of the tree1 object inside playerResources